# Monitor database changes in my asp.net page

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I am having an `ASP.Net` page and a `MySQL` database. In the page am using a `Gridview` for showing the data in the database. The grid:-

- Binds in page load
- Rebinds after **Insert** values
- Rebinds after **delete** a value
- Rebinds after **update** value/s

In short for all the above scenarios i need to rebind the grid. May i know is their any possibility to monitor the database changes in the page, so that i can rebind the grid if any changes occurred for the database.

Have to do something like this algorithm:

```
If IsTheir any change in myDatabase.Mytable then
    MyGrid.ReBind
End If
```

Comment: are you familiar of using sessions?

Comment: @ Dale : what can i do with session in this situation? could you please explain?

Comment: **NOTE: there is no chance of getting the full bounty from answering this question.**

Comment: I have done this type of thing years ago when developing stock trading applications where we could have no DELAYS and the data was updates several hundreds to thousand times per second. Step one in achieving this was to throw away data aware components and develop multicast and tcp ip custom servers. I doubt this can be elegantly solved with data aware component. Having said that it has been years since I touched any DA components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not solve your problem as I'm using `SqlServer` and `C#`. It may help others those who may get similar problems.

You can use a sqlDataSource where you can provide CRUD commands and respective parameters. For eg:

```
on aspx page:

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:connectionStringName %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT  * FROM [TableName] WHERE ([PrimaryFieldID] = @ID) "
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="ID" DbType="Int" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        SqlDataSource.SelectParameters["fieldValue1"].DefaultValue = value1;
        SqlDataSource.SelectParameters["fieldValue2"].DefaultValue = value2;
        SqlDataSource.SelectParameters["ID"].DefaultValue = value;
    }
}

protected void SqlDataSource_Selected(object sender, SqlDataSurceStatusEventArgs e){
// Here you can check for effectedRows
    if((e.AffectedRows-1)>0){
        // write your code here if rows are affected
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create one table to store command and time of execution TBL_COMMAND_HIST with an identity column.

You can create on scheduled event in MySQL that fires at regular interval of say 1 second (or less).

Store the commands from current running processes that are not already in the TBL_COMMAND_HIST.

Check for the identity column. If the Identity column is newer than what you had previously shown on your front end, show the new records.

This you can do for any of the event in your database without adding any additional trigger.

In addition to that if you want it to be implemented for a particular table, you can introduce triggers to populate your command table.

Based on commands in your command table you can determine if the command is insert, update or delete and refresh your page accordingly.

From front end page you need to continuously ping to check records in your command table.

If there is any new entry, just refresh your page.

Comment: you can use "show processlist;" to list the processes

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MS SQL you can check [SqlDependecy Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx).

If you are using MySql check out [MySqlDependency Class](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlDependency.html).

Haven't use MySqlDependency Class though. Hope this helps you and future readers. :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a timer control to refresh the grid every so often?  Unless you need up-to-the-second data. Seems like a grid re-load every minute or so would be easier than adding triggers or tables and such.